# How objects in a game communicate

Tags: c#, oop, game-engine

Consider a game engine that utilizes a **scene**. Now, a scene can have a list of **actors**, which are the objects in the current scene. The pseudo for this might look like:

```
class Scene
{
    public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

For the game loop, the engine calls Update() on the scene object, which then calls Update() on all of the actors.

Now, my question is this: What is a good method to allow actors to communicate (if actors need to be aware of other actors)? i.e. I might have an actor that represents a bullet. This bullet needs to be aware of all enemy actors (so that the bullet can kill them, etc.) I could provide a handle to each actor that references the current scene the actor is in, but that sounds like a bad idea (giving that kind of access/power to each actor).

I'd like to be able to keep all the actors blinded from other actors and the scene, if possible, and achieve behavior/communication through some contract, but I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: do the actors need to interact with each other automatically?  Like auto-pathing of a sort.  Need to avoid this collision so i need to have 'vision' of whats around me?
If not, I recommend keeping all the actors completely blind and letting some "god" process watch over all the interactions. Have something spawn in the overprocess that watches the bullet for intersections with other actors and fires some event inside actor.  Actor.Die...or Damage...etc etc

Comment: An observer-pattern like what you described might work, but like you said, it only works for events. What if I need actors to behave on their own based on the other actors?

Comment: @Jesse, What do you mean behave on their own based on their actors? If you need only a specific information, like, the other game object moved there, an Observer pattern works fine. If you need closer interaction, you can make an object composed of other objects (see: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). If you give an example, maybe I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: How about generating a Look process.  Something that gets called during whatever step it is that you need this where the actor can "look" around them, given a set vision distance you can then report back the position, identity, and if needed the state of the actors closest to the one performing the Look.  Essentially, Treat it like a MUD.  I look around me, What do I see?

Comment: Thanks Nevyn, I ended up with a mixup of your suggestions and webdreamer's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. [If your game engine is composition based, that may be a solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) (I mean each game object is not defined by its class name but rather by the objects that compose it, and you can interact with those objects). You can also register them all in the Scene and be able to fetch them by name, or getting an array of existent by type (using template methods, for example). You can also use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern): each game object implements an interface providing a service, and other game objects subscribe to that service, and are updated when the values of that other object is updated. There are tons of valid solutions, I'm just contributing with some more. It really depends on what you want to take out from the interactions between the objects.

Comment: I settled with creating an Observer for each Scene that is responsible for invoking methods inside of Actor derivatives. The scene observer has access to all the actors in the scene and can fetch by type. Turns out this works pretty elegantly :)

Comment: I fancy the Observer pattern :) Glad it worked. I also find the Visitor patter usually cumbersome, pretty as it may be.

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution is to use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for this.  The example in the Wikipedia talks about a CAD system, but a game isn't that different in this context.

Comment: This pattern looks a bit much for what I'm trying to accomplish (lots of extra code).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how this could be accomplished cleanly, but one of the most straightforward is some variation of the [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

Comment: I like this pattern, but I'm unsure if it will work in a real-time environment where the objects may need to control themselves based on other objects.